# Divs in template are pushing page out of alignment

Tags: html

I have, with advice from members here, attempted to create divs rather than a table for article layout template. I had reasonable success - the content displayed, but not correctly and it also scrambled the page - I had the comments module, which should sit below the article, pushed up on the right and the article content pushed left and down.  I'm posting the table code along with the divs in the hope that someone can assist (One issue, I think, is that there is a single column spanning 8 rows, 4 of which span 2 columns and 4 contain 2 columns, then below this is a further row which spans all 3 columns. I'm confused. For now I've retained the table, but I would really like to learn how to do this correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Jude

Table:

```
<table id='display' width=648 border=0 summary="">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=7 width=228><?php echo $item->fields_by_id[3]->result; ?></td>
        <td width=200><b>Author:</b></td>
        <td width=220><?php echo $item->fields_by_id[1]->result; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width=200><b>Publisher:</b></td>
        <td width=220><?php echo $item->fields_by_id[2]->result; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width=200><b>Genre:</b></td>
        <td width=220><?php echo $item->fields_by_id[9]->result; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width=200><b>CRR Heat Rating:</b></td>
        <td width=220 width=420><?php echo $item->fields_by_id[11]->result; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2 width=420><?php echo $item->fields_by_id[12]->result; ?>
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2 width=420><?php echo $item->fields_by_id[10]->result; ?>
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2 width=420><?php echo $item->fields_by_id[13]->result; ?>
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=3 width=648><?php echo $item->fields_by_id[4]->result; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=3 width=648><?php echo $item->fields_by_id[5]->result; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Divs:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="article">
        <div>
            <div style="float:left;">
                <div><?php echo $item->fields_by_id[3]->result; ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div style="float:left;">
                <div><b>Author:</b></div>
                <div><b>Publisher:</b></div>
                <div><b>Genre:</b></div>
                <div><b>CRR Heat Rating:</b></div>
                <div><?php echo $item->fields_by_id[12]->result; ?></div>
                <div><?php echo $item->fields_by_id[10]->result; ?></div>
                <div><?php echo $item->fields_by_id[13]->result; ?></div>
                <div><?php echo $item->fields_by_id[5]->result; ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div style="float:left;">
                <div><?php echo $item->fields_by_id[1]->result; ?></div>
                <div><?php echo $item->fields_by_id[2]->result; ?></div>
                <div><?php echo $item->fields_by_id[9]->result; ?></div>
                <div><?php echo $item->fields_by_id[11]->result; ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="blurb">
        <div>
            <div style="float:left;">
                <div><?php echo $item->fields_by_id[4]->result; ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No. It's very simple. But I also find that while the table displays correctly (rows and columns) it stretches beyond the width of the page. Very odd, and I'm beyond frustrated... sigh

Comment: I did find that when I added <span> </span> (just trying my luck) it restored the comments to below the article, but the article isn't displaying in columns, it's all vertical

Answer (score 0):

`float` makes that the element has no height anymore, which causes all kinds of 'funny' stuff. I think you are searching for `display: table` and `display: table-cell`. Otherwise you can use `clear: left;` or `clear: both` on the element that should be displayed under the left-floating elements.

---

To get the `display: table` and `display: table-cell` working, you'll have to remove one div-wrapper around each column.

```
<div id="article">
  <div>
    <div><?php echo $item->fields_by_id[3]->result; ?></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div><b>Author:</b></div>
    <div><b>Publisher:</b></div>
    <div><b>Genre:</b></div>
    <!-- etc -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Then use the following CSS:

```
#article {
  display: table;
}

#article > div {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: I'm on a learning curve here, so please can you be patient. Where do I add the css? In the same template file or as custom css (which my template does allow for). Also, just so I know, what is the difference between the table here and an actual table - yes it may be a silly question but it has me confused.

Comment: The difference between this and a table element, is that a table was designed to display tabular data and div's are designed to style documents. It makes a difference for search engines. I believe, div's displayed as tables are displayed more consistently across browsers too. You can add the css anywhere you want, as long as it is included in the document (or you can add it as inline style). `#article > div` means all `div` that are a direct child of `#article`.